# Ping: sendmsg: operation not permitted error after installing iptables on Arch GNU/Linux

Tags: networking, iptables, nat, arch-linux

Yesterday I got a new computer as my homeserver, a HP Proliant Microserver.
Installed Arch Linux on it, with kernel version 3.2.12.

After installing iptables (1.4.12.2 - the current version AFAIK) and changing the `net.ipv4.ip_forward` key to 1, and enabling forwarding in the iptables configuration file (and rebooting), the system cannot use any of its network interfaces. Ping fails with

```
Ping: sendmsg: operation not permitted
```

If I remove iptables completely, networking is okay, but I need to share the Internet connection to the local network.

**eth0** - wan NIC integrated on the motherboard (Broadcom NetXtreme BCM5723).

**eth1** - lan NIC in a pci-express slot (Intel 82574L Gigabit Network)

Since it works without iptables(server can access the internet, and I can login with ssh from the internal network), I assume it has something to do with iptables. I do not have much experience with iptables, so I used these as reference (separate from each other of course...):

[wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Simple_stateful_firewall#Setting_up_a_NAT_gateway](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Simple_stateful_firewall#Setting_up_a_NAT_gateway)

[revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html](http://revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html)

[howtoforge.com/nat_iptables](http://howtoforge.com/nat_iptables)

On my previous server, I used the revsys guide to set up nat, worked like a charm.

Anyone experienced anything like this before? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error message:

```
Ping: sendmsg: operation not permitted
```

means that your server is not allowed to send ICMP packets. You need to allow your server to send traffic via one or more of the configured interfaces. You can do this by:

1. Set `OUTPUT` chain policy to `ACCEPT` to allow all outgoing traffic
   from your box:

   ```
   sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
   ```
2. Set `OUTPUT` chain policy to `DROP` and then allow selectively the type of traffic you need.

This applies to all chains not only the `OUTPUT` chain. `INPUT` chain controls the traffic received by your box. `FORWARD` chain deals with traffic forwarded through the box.

Comment: Ping was just an example, could not send udp packets, nor tcp packets...

Comment: Even though, the same idea applies

Comment: Tried what you said, same results. Got the rules from the old server, this partially works. Any client, can lookup domain names, even able to ping them, but cannot browse the web. I installed a proxy as a workaround(since the connection on the server is fine, just like the connection to the server) but a lot of services does not work(Trillian, Skype) this way.

Comment: What is the command to set Output chain policy to accept??

Comment: @JosephAstrahan: `sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT`

Answer (score 7):

To me, on Debian 9, it helped just to reinstall `ping`:

```
apt-get install --reinstall iputils-ping
```

Comment: Also worked on CentOS 7 (upgrade of the package actually `yum upgrade iputils.x86_64`), after cloning "physical" operating system to a VM - not sure if that matters.

Comment: Working with a custom MX Linux respin based on Debian 12 and had the same issue - reinstalling iputils fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to reset all of iptable rules.

Set the default policy on the iptables to ACCEPT:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
#Then flush the rules:
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
```

See also [How to reset Ubuntu 12.04 iptables to default without locking oneself out?](https://serverfault.com/questions/497438/how-to-reset-ubuntu-12-04-iptables-to-default-without-locking-oneself-out/497448#497448)

Answer (score 1):

If you maintain a right set of iptables, you need to allow outgoing ping :

```
# Allow outgoing ping
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```