# How to reset Ubuntu 12.04 iptables to default without locking oneself out?

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-12.04

Could anyone kindly provide the commands to completely reset the iptables (firewall) for Ubuntu 12.04 to its default "factory" setting? From what I understand, doing this wrong would cause one to be locked out of the linux box?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Set the default policy on the iptables to ACCEPT:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

Then flush the rules:

```
iptables -F INPUT
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -F FORWARD
```

Note, this will not affect alternate tables, NAT tables, PRE/POST routing tables, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Wing Tang Wong. Will the above completely return the firewall to its Ubuntu default state? What if I have accidentally changed the other tables? How do I return all tables to default? Thanks!

Comment: You can make use of iptables-save and iptables-restore. Basically, dump your iptables config to a file. Make sure the three primary are default ACCEPT, and then delete the other table types from the dump file. Then, import it back into the running system with iptables-restore.  That should get you to a clean state. 

This presumes you can't or don't want to reboot the box.

Comment: Gotcha. Question: what if I reboot the box? What will happen? Thanks!

Comment: If you disable all iptable rules that would kick off on a reboot, the default rules for a freshly booted box would default to just the three tables in ACCEPT mode. The other tables would disappear. 

Assuming the rules you were dealing with before were done manually, then a reboot would clear them. However, if they came up that way, then you will need to find and disable/comment out/remove the rules getting installed at startup.

Comment: The given solution would work only if you didn't install the persistent iptables
If you did, you should need to do the folowing comand: `sudo apt-get remove iptables-persistent`

Comment: `Note, this will not affect alternate tables, NAT tables, PRE/POST routing tables, etc.` Yeah, a lot is missing. Here's what it looks like if you want to follow [this way](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/da5de61959ae118900b685fed78feff1). And you might want to add `iptables -t "$table" -Z`. Do note that this way you're hardcoding the list of the tables and their chains. But I'm not sure if the order of the commands is safe. So I would seriously consider [save-restore solution](https://serverfault.com/a/200642/162443). Or you can just [unload iptables](https://serverfault.com/a/973412/162443).

Answer (score 32):

This thing seem to be ok.. 
http://insanelabs.com/linux/linux-reset-iptables-firewall-rules/

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

Comment: Man, you don't know how grateful I am for you post!!!! After several hours of painful debugging I finally changed my iptables to default and my problem is now fixed! My problem was that I had nodejs server that worked just fine on localhost:80 and also myip:80 but I also had one more nodejs server that worked on localhost:4000 but didn't worked on myip:4000 and I was very frustrated because this happened after installing mail server on my raspberri pi and this happened all of a sudden. Again man, you have a beer from me! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

[Wing's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/497448/381661) will be at your rescue when things go wrong with `iptables`. If you want to reset everything, including alternate tables, `NAT`, `PRE/POST ROUTING`, use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# rc.flush-iptables - Resets iptables to default values.
#
# Copyright (C) 2001 Oskar Andreasson <bluefluxATkoffeinDOTnet>
#
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.
#
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with this program or from the site that you downloaded it
# from; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple
# Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA
#
# Configurations
#
IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"
#
# reset the default policies in the filter table.
#
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
#
# reset the default policies in the nat table.
#
$IPTABLES -t nat -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t nat -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
#
# reset the default policies in the mangle table.
#
$IPTABLES -t mangle -P PREROUTING ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t mangle -P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t mangle -P INPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t mangle -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -t mangle -P FORWARD ACCEPT
#
# flush all the rules in the filter and nat tables.
#
$IPTABLES -F
$IPTABLES -t nat -F
$IPTABLES -t mangle -F
#
# erase all chains that's not default in filter and nat table.
#
$IPTABLES -X
$IPTABLES -t nat -X
$IPTABLES -t mangle -X
```

Source: [Internet Connection Sharing - Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing)